# Access sqlite db which is placed locally on the server

Tags: php, sqlite

I am developing a php application that needs to query an sqlite database which is not placed in the www folder. I am using the following code to connect.

```
$db = sqlite_open($path, 0666, $sqliteerror);
```

but there is some kind of error. My app is placed in httpdocs section. so how can i specify the path to my db?

```
$path='/srv/smartfox/Server/db/myDB.sqlite';
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "Some kind of error". It is difficult to read minds these days :)

Comment: lol it says "server error" when i upload the file but if i dont try to connect the db..then everything goes smoothly. can i know what the exact error is by printing $sqliteerror?

Comment: @Salmanmahmood I don't know... can you? (i.e. have you tried?)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

- The PHP process has to have read access to the database file.
- The PHP process has to have write access to the file *and* the enclosing folder if you're trying to write to the database (Sqlite might need this even if you're not writing, but I'm not sure about that).
- You might not have the Sqlite extension enabled. Check it with `phpinfo()`.

Try this:

- Enable error logging to see what error you get.
- Try accessing a database inside your `httpdocs` folder. Does that work?
- Use PDO to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the path between apostrophes:

```
$path='/srv/smartfox/Server/db/myDB.sqlite';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check root directory for your script by: **$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]** and then decide the path for the sqlite file. I think there might be a problem regarding the path. If your control is in 'www' directory than use:

```
$path = 'srv/smartfox/Server/db/myDB.sqlite';
```

Hope it might work!!!